# Refreshing content automatically when new tuple is added to the DB

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm at the conceptualizing stage of developing something but not quite sure of a certain feature.

I have a DIV in a form, lets call it id='divComments'. This div contains all of the comments on a particular title. It retrieves all of the data from the database which is easy to do.

Now when the page is refreshed, this div is populated with all of the comments. If another user adds a comment, all of the other users will see this comment when they log on (after that point in time) or if they refresh the page.

What if I want this div feeding from the database and refreshes automatically when something is inserted into the relation/table in the Database? so I have my page opened (im not refreshing it, just staring at it) showing lets say x and someone else adds a tuple in the particular database table lets call that y, and my div now shows x and y. In other words its updating real time from the database without refreshing.

Anyone has any idea how to go about doing something like this?

Comment: There's no way for your downstream HTML to "listen" for changes at the database level. However, you can implement an Ajax solution to periodically refresh the records from the database.

Comment: Ok. Then I must ask how is a chatroom implemented like the one at chatropolis?

Comment: The HTML itself cannot do anything once it's sent to the client. Any changes after that involve AJAX phoning home to get the newest data ... there might be a js call every second (or even more frequently). I can't speak to how "chatropolis" specifically implements such a solution.

Comment: AJAX calls every second (or more frequently) isn't a great idea. You may want to consider some sort of two-way communication method such as [socket.io](http://socket.io/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP is stateless.  Once an asset has finished downloading through a HTTP connection, the connection is destroyed and the server no longer has any knowledge of what the client is doing next.

There are ways of fudging stateful behaviour, using cookies and sessions and the like, but these still require a new connection to the server to fetch fresh data.

There are technologies in development that can allow a web server to "push" new data to the client the instant it becomes available (websockets, server-sent events, etc), but these are still at the draft stage for the most part and browser support is spotty at best.

The only real choice you have is polling the server with a refresh meta tag (EXTREMELY inefficient!), polling the server with AJAX (Better, in that you can design it to only fetch the data that's changed, but still not ideal), or using a long-lasting AJAX connection that remains idle until new data becomes available, at which point the data is downloaded, the connection is closed, and a new connection is opened to sit idle for more data (will allow immediate response, but difficult to set up properly).

Comment: "or using a long-lasting AJAX connection that remains idle until new data becomes available, at which point the data is downloaded, the connection is closed, and a new connection is opened to sit idle for more data (will allow immediate response, but difficult to set up properly)."  ----------> could you give me some key words for research on this? I think its exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: It's called AJAX with long polling.  It's also sometimes known as Comet, though it's really just one of several techniques that can be used to implement Comet.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29#Ajax_with_long_polling

Comment: Did some quick research on comet but have some questions. From what I'm seeing the heart of it is an infinite loop with the server page to keep checking if a file modification date has changed. Of course there are other stuff but from what I'm seeing it's the heart of the update. The infinite loop has a little break of probably 100 ms to avoid clogging the cpu.

Comment: But if we're talking about 100 users accessing my application simultaneously I'm wondering if this might overburden the server's cpu. wouldn't it be better to have the infinite loop somewhere in the middle of AJAX code so that it would be the user's computer helping with the execution and not only the server? Let's say I develop a simple method checking every 500 ms to the server for if there are any changes. I'm thinking it might be better, it's like distributing the work involved. Do you agree with me or am I misinterpreting?

Comment: Comet isn't something you can implement easily in PHP, so it's probably best avoided.  The only real choice is to have the client check every few seconds for changes by having it poll the server every 10 seconds or so.

Comment: Yea I think that is the most intelligent way to go. Thanks for you help man!